# Create/Show Rows based on the value in the other cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I was hoping for some help.

I have a dropdown list in cell "I2" and Hidden Name Ranges. I would like to show Name Range 1 if 1 is selected in "I2" cell.  Show Name Range 1 and Name Range 2 if 2 is selected in "I2". Show Name Range 1 and Name Range 2 and Name Range 3 if 3 is selected in "I2" and so on.

[image]

I know I could use If statement for all 30 possible combinations but this would be very repetitive

```
If Worksheets("sheet1").Range("I2").Value = 1 Then
            Range("NameRange1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("NameRange2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("NameRange3).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            .... and so on
```

Is there another efficient way to for example a loop through the range to hide unhide desired rows ? Or perhaps there is a separate procedure I could use to create rows (row 6, row 7 row 8 etc ..)'On the fly' based on the value in cell "I2" . That way I could instantly create rows that are needed. I'm sorry if I'm being vague but considering best possible options here

Any advise hugely appreciated. Thanks  :)

Comment: Try a `For...Next` loop combining the value of current loop (1,2,3...) with your named ranges (Name1, Name2, Name3...)

Comment: When using the loop ```Sub HideRows()

Dim cell As Range

StartRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("NameRange1")
EndRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("NameRange30")

For i = StartRow To EndRow
 If Range("I1").Value > 0 Then
cells(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
cells(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next i

End Sub``` Im getting  application defined or object defined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following routine will show ranges up to a certain number and hide all the others. It will loop over all ranges and check if the range number is larger than the given number `showUntilRange`. As the `hidden`-property is a boolean, you can simply use the term `(i > showUntilRange)`.

```
Sub showHideRanges(showUntilRange As Long)
    Const rangeCount As Long = 30
    Const rangeNamePrefix As String = "NameRange"
    
    Dim i As Long, rangeName As String, r As Range
    For i = 1 To rangeCount
        rangeName = rangeNamePrefix & i
        On Error Resume Next
        Set r = Nothing
        Set r = Range(rangeName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "couldn't find range " & rangeName
        Else
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = (i > showUntilRange)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Your event routine could look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("I2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    showHideRanges CLng(Target)
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant it worked as expected. Thanks a lot. Going back to my other question. Is there a way to make separate procedure to create rows on the fly?  Forget about all predefined name ranges. Let's say I manually type a number in cell "I2" and new rows are automatically inserted between "some text" in the picture above based on amount I typed in "I2" Is it possible ? starting from row 6 for example.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
Dim rStart As Integer
Dim rEnd As Integer
Dim i As Integer
    rStart = Range("NameRange1").Row
    rEnd = Range("NameRange30").Row
    
    For i = rStart To rEnd
        Range("NameRange" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = (i = Range("I2").Value)
    Next i
```

The `For .. Next Loop` loops though all named ranges. If the Name matches the Value of the dropdown cell, the entire row is shown. If the match fails, the entire row is hidden.